# Computed variable with properties in KnockoutJS?

Tags: knockout.js

Can a computed variable have properties?

For example, I have user input of room dimensions, and I want them to be put through some scaling logic that something else on the screen needs to read from.

When either Width, Height, or Depth is updated, I need to update ALL of ScaledRoom W/H/D, as there's going to be a fair bit of logic that changes all three values depending on situations.

```
var MyViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    //Room Dimensions
    self.RoomWidth = ko.observable();
    self.RoomHeight = ko.observable();
    self.RoomDepth = ko.observable();


    //basic psuedocode of what I want to achieve... Haven't put in the previously mentioned logic in order to keep it simple
    self.ScaledRoom = ko.computed(function () {
        this.Width = self.RoomWidth * 10;
        this.Height = self.RoomHeight * 15;
        this.Depth = self.RoomDepth * 11;
        return this;
    });

};
```

In the html, i'd like to be able to databind to ScaledRoom.Width() for example

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Can't you just have 3 computed properties?

Comment: I'd need to triplicate some of my logic then, doesn't seem ideal. Also when one computed changed it'd need to update the other two computed.... Although I think I've discovered you can create writable computeds which may solve that issue

Comment: You still shouldn't need to. Each computed could call a function which is shared. What logic would you need to share.

Comment: That's a good point, I neglected to put my logic in another function when I tried it this way, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate model for ScaledRoom:

```
var ScaledRoom  = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.Width = ko.observable(0);
    self.Height = ko.observable(0);
    self.Depth = ko.observable(0);
}
```

Then you can have a computed observable which changes the values on the object. The if statement first checks if there is an object. If there is no object then it's created.

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.RoomWidth = ko.observable(0);
    self.RoomHeight = ko.observable(0);
    self.RoomDepth = ko.observable(0);

    self.ScaledRoom = ko.computed(function () {
        var scaledRoom;
        if (!self.ScaledRoom) {
            scaledRoom = new ScaledRoom();
        }
        else {
            scaledRoom = self.ScaledRoom();
        }

        scaledRoom.Width(self.RoomWidth() * 10);
        scaledRoom.Height(self.RoomHeight() * 15);
        scaledRoom.Depth(self.RoomDepth() * 11);

        return scaledRoom;
    });
};
```

View:

```
<div>
    Room Width: <input type="text" data-bind="value: RoomWidth"/>
</div>
<div>
    Room Height: <input type="text" data-bind="value: RoomHeight"/>
</div>
<div>
    Room Depth: <input type="text" data-bind="value: RoomDepth"/>
</div>
<div data-bind="with: ScaledRoom">
    <div data-bind="text: Width"></div>
    <div data-bind="text: Height"></div>
    <div data-bind="text: Depth"></div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bmk3eo4m/

Comment: A good start, but I think OP's better served with the suggestion of *entirely* moving to an OO approach, binding inputs to a `ScaledRoom` as well. Saves about 10 lines of code too. ([updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmk3eo4m/1/))

Comment: @Jeroen I did think about doing that but I tried to stick to what the question was specifically asking for